# Shopify jQuery page navigation - grab nav titles by id

Tags: jquery, navigation, shopify

I have a Shopify site that has long blog articles, and I am looking for a way to create navigation for the article on the left side of the blog page template based on the H2 tags.

I have used some simple jQuery and id's to make links to the different parts of the page. Here's what I have so far.

HTML (template)

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <ul class="article-nav">
      <li><a href="{{ article.url }}/#g1" alt="" id="title1">Group 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{ article.url }}/#g2" alt="" id="title2">Group 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{ article.url }}/#g3" alt="" id="title3">Group 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{ article.url }}/#g4" alt="" id="title4">Group 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    {{ article.content }}
  </div>
```

Now here's the code from the blog post itself

```
<h2 id="g1">This is my first title</h2>
<p>Some content ...</p>
<h2 id="g2">This is my second title</h2>
<p>Some content ...</p>
...
```

Here's the jQuery I have to put it all together

```
var tr1 = $(g1).text();
var tr2 = $(g2).text();
var tr3 = $(g3).text();
var tr4 = $(g4).text();
$(title1).html( tr1 );
$(title2).html( tr2 );
$(title3).html( tr3 );
$(title4).html( tr4 );
```

I am not an expert at javascript or jQuery. Is there any way to simplify this code? It looks like I'm writing too much at the moment and it could be tightened up.

Answer (score 0):

with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rows = 4;//quantity of articles
    for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++ ){
      var txt = $('#g'+i).text();
      $('#title'+i).html(txt);
    }
})
```